# Linkedin Ads API getting 500 server error while trying to fetch Conversions

Tags: linkedin-api

While trying to fetch conversionsCount for a specific Linkedin Ads account I am getting this error. {"status": 500, "message": "Id is missing for pivot: ACCOUNT"}

This was the query params and this was the conversions URL i used. I am testing with 2 Ads accounts. Its working for our test account, but its giving this error for the client account.

URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adConversionReportStatistics
QUERY PARAMS: {"count": 1000, "oauth2_access_token": "TOKEN", "endsAt": 1507919400000, "period": "ALL", "q": "criteria", "start": 0, "accounts": "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:XYZ", "startsAt": 1506796200000, "pivot": "ACCOUNT"}